# Zip a folder on S3 using Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, zip

I have an application where in I need to zip folders hosted on S3.The zipping process will be triggered from the model save method.The Django app is running on an EC2 instance.Any thoughts or leads on the same?

I tried django_storages but haven't got a breakthrough

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding you can't zip files directly on s3. you would have to download the files you'd want to zip, zip them up, then upload the zipped file. i've done something similar before and used s3cmd to keep a local synced copy of my s3bucket, and since you're on an ec2 instance network speed and latency will be pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for your input.Can you please share a snippet if you don't mind? Iv been stuck on this endlessly